# Overpayment of Wages from ex-employer

Tags: united-kingdom, legal

I left my old job on Friday 9th August. They made it clear to me I wasn't wanted.

They paid me a full month on the 23rd and I queried this by emailing them. Somebody from payroll said they'd get back to me.

A letter arrived stating they had overpaid me by £700 and they insisted the full amount is paid in full immediately. If I didn't respond to the letter, it would be referred to their solicitor.

However, I haven't received my P45 yet (I left three weeks ago) and I haven't had confirmation of my correct final wage.

I understand I will have to pay something back, but I'm owed holiday pay and the figure won't be £700.

How should I approach this? I've no problem paying them the money because it isn't mine, but I've no P45 or a correct figure for a final monthly wage.

Overall, the company has treated me shabbily throughout my time there. I'm inclined pay them something like £10 a month because of how the letter was worded.

I'm in the UK. Can somebody offer any advice on how best to approach and resolve this?

Thank you,

Lee.

Comment: In the UK, the Citizens' Advice Bureau offers excellent (and free) employment law advice. If you take along all the paperwork you have they should be able to help.

Comment: You can make the offer of £10 per month and if they took you to court the Judge may well accept that or something similar - especially if they are dragging their feet about sorting the P45 etc... Get to Citizens Advice and get them to deal with the employer, don't give away too much - stick out for all they owe you.

Comment: Paying £10 a month sounds like a good way to get them to botch the administration again. Only do this if you are really keen to stay in touch with the company.

Comment: Did the claim you had been overpaid by £700 include a breakdown of that money? Do you have your own figures on how much you believe you are owed?

Answer (score 5):

**In your case:**

If they are threatening you with lawyers then you need proper legal advice. As suggested in the comments you can get free legal advice from the Citizens Advice Bureau.

**In most cases:**

If you have been overpaid then you are obliged to repay the employer (within your ability to do so).

However, it is entirely reasonable to ask for a complete and accurate breakdown of the figures before doing so. This could be in the form of a P45 or it could be a small spreadsheet or whatever.

The company got it wrong the first time around so it would be sensible to check their working before returning any money.

Comment: They have no choice but to give you the P45, it is a legal requirement, not something "reasonable"...

Comment: There are other, very similar, scenarios which have an identical answer but where a P45 wouldn't come into play. For example, an employee could be overpaid while still working for their employer, perhaps due to maternity leave or a change in working patterns.

Comment: As the OP made clear, he left the employer, so definitely NOT still working for them...